# Python string to usable expression/function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, equation

While trying to do some spline interpolating, I have run into an issue. I have code that creates many spline equations on a given interval. An example of one of the equations might look like...

```
0 + (1.0 * (x - 0)) + (0.0 * (x - 0)**2) + (0.0 * (x - 0)**3)
```

Currently all my equations are in the from of strings. Now I am at a point where I want to plug in values to 'x' based on some other constraints and get values back from them. What would be the best way to use these equations now that I have generated them?

I have looked at the python `eval` function as well as a few other options from numpy/scipy, but I just cant seem to find the right way to convert these strings into useable equations.Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at numexpr

Answer (score -1):

So to anyone else who may run across this same issue, I found a "hacky" way to do this for now. I am just using `replace` on the above string to replace the 'x' with a numeric value. Than I am able to use eval to get a number from it.

For example:

```
>> eq = "0 + (1.0 * (x - 0)) + (0.0 * (x - 0)**2) + (0.0 * (x - 0)**3)"
>> eq = eq.replace("x", "1.1")
>> eval(eq)
1.1
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the need for the hack? Just set `x = 1.1` before calling `eval(eq)`.

Comment: The reason I had to do it this way is because I currently have a list of equations like the one in the original question. I also need to be able to access each equation more than once and plug in multiple values.

Comment: You can reassign x and call eval(eq) at will.